# What do these sentences from "When Dinosaurs Roamed North Dakota" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, commas, dashes

> [W]e passed rolling hills with emerald green grass, farmhouses dotting
>   acres of fields and wild, rocky landscapes. (Hillary Richard, "[When Dinosaurs Roamed North Dakota](https://www.nytimes.com/2017/07/11/travel/north-dakota-badlands-fossils-dinosaurs-prehistoric-public-digs.html)", *New York
>   Times*)

I understood the sentence as the following:

*We passed rolling hills with emerald green grass that had farmhouses dotting a big area composed of fields and wild, rocky landscapes.*

Does this sound intuitively right?

Or could it be read as:
*"We passed three things: 1. rolling hills with emerald green grass 2. farmhouses dotting acres of fields 3. wild, rocky landscapes."*

I believe grammatically both are correct, but I am wondering how most of you would read it intuitively.

Also, from the same article,

> The convoy — eight adults including a mother with an adolescent boy —
>   turned off the highway

How many people do you read to be in the convoy? In the story later, the adolescent boy appears, so it's not saying a mother who has an adolescent boy came by herself.

To me, it sounds 9 people: 8 adults and 1 adolescent boy, but grammatically "eight adults" is a nominal appositive to "the convoy." Then are we counting the boy as one of the 8 adults?

Comment: The farmhouses are likely to be in the acres of fields rather than the wild, rocky landscapes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sentence you are quoting is from [When Dinosaurs Roamed North Dakota](https://www.nytimes.com/2017/07/11/travel/north-dakota-badlands-fossils-dinosaurs-prehistoric-public-digs.html), and in the full article is preceded by "The nearly 100-mile drive dispelled any myth that North Dakota is flat."

The location of the dinosaur dig was in Dickinson, which is directly west of Bismarck on the I-94.  If you look at a satellite view on Google, you'll see that the land is mostly agricultural with occasional forested areas, although the area around Dickinson itself looks more rugged.

Given that additional information, I would interpret the "rolling hills with emerald green grass, farmhouses dotting acres of fields and wild, rocky landscapes" as **a list of things that the writer saw, probably more than once**.  The list is there mainly to illustrate that North Dakota is not as flat as most readers of the  NY Times might think.

It's likely that all three things were sometimes visible at the same time, so both of your interpretations are reasonable, and they both serve the writer's purpose of giving you a picture of land that is **not flat**.

Concerning the second sentence ("including a mother with an adolescent boy"), the writer is clearly writing from an adult perspective, where a child is being brought along by the adult parent.  I think you're correct in judging the total number of people to be nine.